# How to test curl "CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT"

Tags: php, curl

Is there any way of testing CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT?

I have a curl that has this line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5 );
```

But how to test that it actually tries to connect for 5s and only after then it stops trying to connect and moves on?

If I shut down the server, curl doesn't wait at all because it thinks there is no need to. If I put the requested php-script to sleep, curl waits for that sleep-time, because there is connection but the script is just taking so long.

I use local WAMP-server as the one who calls, and the call is sent to local php-server with symfony.

Comment: Why do you need to test curl if I may ask?

Comment: @PeeHaa: I like to test everything myself. It's not that I don't trust the docs, but I still like to make sure everything works exactly as planned. :) So no fatal injuries happening if I cannot test this, but I'm just curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be tested if curl connects to a non-routable IP address  10.255.255.1.

Comment: That IP could be routable on some networks, I believe.

Comment: Quite the old question but never got the answer for this and it did bother me after that. :) But this is actually a good answer I think! Never thought of connecting to a non-routable ip! Thanks buddy!